# Use s3-pit-restore inside a lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I'm wondering if it's possible to import and use this tool in a lambda function written in Python and how to do it

https://github.com/angeloc/s3-pit-restore

Comment: Yes, it's very easy. Bundle it up and deploy as a zip file to AWS Lambda, and put `{module path separated with .}.{function name}` as handler on Lambda.

Comment: can also look into AWS CDK to deploy function in python runtime and bundle code automatically as zip, but I feel this might be overkill for this use case in particular, as `boto3` is a built-in library in Lambda already.